# List of delegates and invoking

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, invoke

I am creating a smaller RPG game in ASP.NET. In this game I have an items architecture, where each item has some methods. For instance, all items should share a method like "**Drop**", "**Examine**" and "**Use**". Some items will have to be extended with methods like "**Operate**", "**Calculate**" and such.

So far, I have created the following object GameActionList:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();

public class GameActionList
{
    public List<MyDelegate> Items = new List<MyDelegate>();

    public void Add(MyDelegate del)
    {
        Items.Add(del);
    }

    public void CallDelegates()
    {
        foreach (MyDelegate myDelegate in Items)
        {
            myDelegate();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a BaseItem class, which has this GameActionList. The get property of this in the BaseItem class is like this:

```
    public GameActionList Actions 
    { 
        get
        {
            GameActionList actions = new GameActionList();
            actions.Add(this.Drop);
            actions.Add(this.Examine);
            return actions;
        }
    }
```

This is fine, BUT... I have some problems!

**My problem**

I need a way more generic GameActionList. I need to have a list of not only voids, but also functions.. Also, I need both methods with parameters and without parameters.

For instance: The **Drop** method will need a Player object, so he can Drop the item. The **Examine** method will need to return a string descriping the item.

Also, I need some data which I don't know when I Initialize the GameActionList: I first know these data when I invoke the method...

So I have two questions:

1. How do you extend the GameActionList, so it can contain a list of both voids and functions andalso these both can have parameters or not.. (AND DOES IT EVEN MAKE SENSE??)
2. How can I give some data to the method later in the cycle, like when invoking?

*Also... This might be a very stupid way to do it, so if you have some way more elegant solution.. I'm more than ready to hear it*!

Thanks a lot...!
Lars

Comment: Thanks alot for notice :) I didn't know that feature.. Just accepted the correct answers of last questions.. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you most probably need Action , Func  delegates

[Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)

[Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Just researched it and updated my code - it works really good! Now I just have to learn the DynamicInvoke.. Oh well!

Great :) Thanks